# Gerenciando dependências Composer

Tags: php, composer

Bom, comecei a utilizar o gerenciador de dependências para PHP Composer.  Já fiz o Download e está funcionando. Porém adicionei uma dependência no arquivo `composer.json`, e preciso fazer um update. Como posso fazer isso via linha de comando?

PS: Sei muito pouco sobre como usar o Prompt de comando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entre no diretório do projeto pela linha de comando e rode o seguinte comando:

```
composer update
```

Se você já tiver o arquivo `composer.lock` (que é onde o Composer salva as referências a cada uma das dependências que estão no projeto), rode o seguinte comando:

```
composer install
```

O comando acima depende bastante do composer estar disponível globalmente pela linha de comando ou não. Você pode preferir baixar o executável do Composer no próprio projeto com um dos seguintes comandos:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Ou, se você não tiver `curl`:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

E aí bastaria só substituir `composer` por `composer.phar`, que é o nome do arquivo baixado.

Comment: Pode me mostrar como entro no diretório? O caminho é esse C: -> wamp -> www -> crm.

Comment: O comando é `cd c:\wamp\www\crm`. Qualquer coisa, vá usando a tecla `tab` a cada diretório para ver os sub-diretórios a partir do ponto que você está para facilitar a navegação :)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!