# Autoload do composer não funciona?

Tags: php, composer, php-autoload

Estou tentando usar o `autoload` do `composer` e não consigo, ele fala que a classe `not found` e tentando carregar uma classe de uma biblioteca externa.

Já executei na linha de comando:

```
composer install
```

e

```
composer dump
```

sem sucesso.

---

***composer.json***

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4":
    {
        "App\\":
        [
            "app/",
            "tests/"
        ]
    }
}
```

***Código***

```
<?php

  namespace App\Database;
  use Dotenv\Dotenv;

  $dotenv = new Dotenv('../../');
  $dotenv->load();


  class Database
  {...
```

***Erro***

> `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Dotenv\Dotenv' not found in /home/vagrant/Projetos/qa-toll/src/Database/Database.php on line 7`

Comment: No seu código aonde é carregado `vendor/autoload.php` não está descrito no código?

Comment: Ele não é carregado aumoáticamente para os namespaces App?

Comment: ele só vai carregar automaticamente quando no topo do `script` tive `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` ai você pode utilizar entendeu ... ? ou coisa tem que dar um `composer dump-autoload` para que ele crie as entradas no arquivo de carregamento.

Comment: Se a resposta for útil aceita ela como resposta?

Answer (score 2):

O `autoload` do `composer.phar` funciona da seguinte forma, ao instalar os pacotes e ou configurar alguma classe existe um arquivo que é obrigatório a sua declaração no topo do `script` para que tenha acesso a todo código produzido pelo desenvolvedor ou baixado pelo `composer`.

Como seria um layout das pastas:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

após fazer todas as suas configurações e baixar o seu pacote o seu arquivo `composer.json` tem as configurações abaixo:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": [
                "app/",
                "tests/"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

e para que essas modificações entre em vigor, faça o comando:

```
php composer dump-autoload
```

pronto. Agora para utilizar todo o código, inclusive de pacotes instalados, deve colocar no topo do arquivo e incluir `require vendor/autoload.php`, ***exemplo***:

***index.php***

```
<?php

    // aqui que define todo o carregamento e disponibilidade do código
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use Dotenv\Dotenv;
    use App\Database;

    $dotEnv = new Dotenv(__DIR__);
    $dotEnv->load();

    $database = new Database();
    echo $database->getConfigServer();
```

***Boa leitura:***

- [Composer não instala pacotes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116420/composer-n%C3%A3o-instala-pacotes)
- [Gerenciando dependências Composer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58119/gerenciando-depend%C3%AAncias-composer)
- [Qual é a diferença entre o dump-autoload normal e o otimizado, no Composer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123097/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-dump-autoload-normal-e-o-otimizado-no-composer)
- [NPM, Bower e Composer, qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175504/npm-bower-e-composer-qual-usar)
- [Como definir a semântica de pacotes baixados com composer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165871/como-definir-a-sem%C3%A2ntica-de-pacotes-baixados-com-composer)
- [Composer - Autoload e PSR-0 vs PSR-4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19200/composer-autoload-e-psr-0-vs-psr-4)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @tiagopaes se foi util aceite como resposta da sua pergunta!